# Default the current month in input type month in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get the current month in an input type month in vue.js, but I have no clue how, does anybody have a clue please?

HTML:

```
<input type="month" v-model="month">
```

JS:

```
data()
    {
        return{
            date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)
        };
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v-model` attribute on your `input` element is not referencing your `date` data property. It does not know where to bind its input value:

```js
<input type="month" v-model="date">
```

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements. It automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem, the slice was not doing the right amount it should be:

new Date().toISOString().substr(0,7)

instead of

new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10)